# Finding the bounds of a triple integral (spherical coordinates)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I'm currently learning how to calculate the volume of a 3D surface expressed in spherical coordinates using triple integrals.
There was this exercice (from [here](https://opentextbc.ca/calculusv3openstax/chapter/triple-integrals-in-cylindrical-and-spherical-coordinates/)) which asked me to find the volume of the region described by those two equations:

$x^2+y^2=1$

$x^2+y^2+z^2=4$

([The image of the region from the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sLUE.png))

From this I've found that:

$csc\phi\le \rho\le2$ and $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$

I was also able to find a value of $\phi$ which was $\frac{\pi}{6}$ (I wasn't able to deduce if it corresponded to the lower or higher bound).

And from here I didn't knew what to do next, so I assumed that $0\le \phi\le \frac{\pi}{6}$ because I was stucked.

And the actual right setup of the integral in spherical coordinates was:

$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{5\frac{\pi}{6}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{csc(\phi)}^{2}\rho^2sin(\phi) d\rho d\theta d\phi$

So my brain died.

I couldn't figure why first of all $d\theta$ was located before $d\phi$ (what constraint would have caused this ?).

And also why the other bound of $\phi$ was $5\frac{\pi}{6}$, how was I supposed to find this value ?

Comment: Based on how you set up the limits, apparently you are interested in the region outside the cylinder and inside the sphere, instead of the region inside both. But this is something you should make explicit in your statement of the problem, not something that the reader has to figure out from your description of your work. Also "found a value for $\phi$" should be "found *the value of $\phi$ where the cylinder and sphere intersect*" for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\underline{"Outside"}\,\,\, Volume\
{\Large\cal V}_{\mrm{out}} \pars{~\mbox{Cylindrical Coordintaes}~}}$.

Hereafter, $\ds{\bracks{\cdots}}$ is an
[Iverson Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Namely, $\ds{\bracks{P} =
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{1} & \mbox{if}\ P\ \mbox{is}\ true.
\\[1mm]
\ds{0} & \,\,\,\,\,\mbox{if}\ P\ \mbox{is}\ false.
\end{array}\right.}$

---

\begin{align}
{\Large\cal V}_{\mrm{out}} & \equiv
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} > 1}\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} < 4}
\dd^{3}\vec{r}}
\\[5mm] & =
\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\bracks{\rho^{2} > 1}
\bracks{\rho^{2} + z^{2} < 4}
\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd \phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
\bracks{1 < \rho^{2} < 4 - z^{2}}
\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd \phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
\bracks{1 < 4 - z^{2}}
\bracks{1 < \rho < \root{4 - z^{2}}}
\\[2mm] &\ \rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd \phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
\bracks{\verts{z} < \root{3}}
\bracks{1 < \rho < \root{4 - z^{2}}}
\\[2mm] & \rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd \phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
2\pi\int_{-\root{3}}^{\root{3}}
\int_{1}^{\root{4 - z^{2}}}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\pi\int_{-\root{3}}^{\root{3}}\pars{3 - z^{2}}\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{4\root{3}\pi} \approx 21.7656 \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain the notation in the first line? I don't think I've seen it before

Comment: @Buraian I just added the definition and a link at the answer top.

Comment: Thanks, actually, it seems like it's a lot easier to go from cartesian to cylindrical to spherical instead of going straight from cartesian to spherical. With this kind of problem, if for example you had to use spherical coordinates, would you have passed through cylindrical first ? Or am I just not good enough to use directly spherical ?

Answer (score -1):

It does not matter what order $\rho, \theta, \phi$ are integrated in, as long as the limits on each are expressed only in terms of variables yet to be integrated. Since $\theta, \phi$ have constant limits, they can be interchanged freely. Since the limits for $\rho$ and $\theta$ are independent of each other, they can also be exchanged. But to exchange the order of the integrations of $\rho$ and $\phi$, you would need to express the limits of $\phi$ in terms of $\rho$ instead of $\rho$ in terms of $\phi$. However, between the two, your approach is simpler. That is:
$$\begin{align}\int_{\frac{\pi}6}^{\frac{5\pi}6}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\csc \phi}^2\rho^2\sin \phi\, d\rho\, d\theta\, d\phi &= \int_{\frac{\pi}6}^{\frac{5\pi}6}\int_{\csc \phi}^2\int_0^{2\pi}\rho^2\sin \phi\,d\theta\,d\rho\,d\phi \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}6}^{\frac{5\pi}6}\int_{\csc \phi}^2\rho^2\sin \phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta\int_{\frac{\pi}6}^{\frac{5\pi}6}\int_{\csc \phi}^2\rho^2\sin \phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\\
&=2\pi\int_{\frac{\pi}6}^{\frac{5\pi}6}\left(\sin \phi\int_{\csc \phi}^2\rho^2\,d\rho\right)\,d\phi\end{align}$$
since the integrand and limits are constant with respect to $\theta$, the $\sin \phi$ factor of the integrand does not depend on $\rho$.

Now $\int_{\csc \phi}^2\rho^2\,d\rho$ is not hard to figure out. And once you do, the integrand for $\phi$ may not be as bad as you think.